# GetWeekOfYear with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've a column in my table called `Date`, and I need to compare this date's `WeekOfTheYear` with `DateTime.Now`'s `WeekOfTheYear`,

If I give like this,

```
var cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;

int week = cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

I am getting `26` here. The same way, in my Entity Framework, I need to compare this week's data, for this I tried like,

```
entities.WorkingDays.Where(a => 
             cal.GetWeekOfYear(a.DATE,CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,DayOfWeek.Sunday)
             == cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,
                                                 DayOfWeek.Sunday)
```

when I run the query like this, am getting error like,

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetWeekOfYear
>   (System.DateTime, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule, System.DayOfWeek)'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

How can I fetch the data for weekly basis here, can any one help me out here....thanks in advance

Comment: I think this will [not be possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538995/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method) with Linq to Entities [Also this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880011/entity-framework-all-method)

Comment: Is it just this week number for this year, or for all years? If it's just this year or a small number of years then rather than test the week number in LINQ you could compute the start and end dates for that week in C# and then compare against that date range in the LINQ query instead.

Comment: I first read the question as "Geek of the Year" ... :)

Answer (score 2):

Call .ToList() first. Like this:

```
entities.WorkingDays.ToList().Where(a => 
             cal.GetWeekOfYear(a.DATE,CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,DayOfWeek.Sunday)
             == cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,
                                                 DayOfWeek.Sunday)
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316615/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32) post for duplicate issue. Basically, the data needs to be in memory before using your GetWeekOfYear functions.

As noted in the comments, this does bring the whole "WorkingDays" table into memory and therefore fetching more data than needed from the DB. Sometimes this is more preferable to using Stored Procedures and sometimes not, depending on the amount of data and other factors based on your application/database architecture.

Comment: No problem, ran into this myself a few days ago.

Comment: Note that this means you're loading the table from the database then filtering it as opposed to filtering it at the database end, which is going to be less efficient and make any further manipulations less efficient too

Comment: Doing .ToList would fetch more data than needed from the database - but I guess its such a small amount in this instance so it's OK :) (edit: Rup beat me to it)

Comment: @Rup and cederlof, yes, that is most certainly the case, but sometimes you have to take that tradeoff, or use stored procedures instead. I'll update the answer to make that more clear.

Comment: @ whoever, Please leave feedback for future improvement if you down vote.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the day of year and divide it with 7 on both instances, and get a sufficient result?

```
Date.DayOfYear / 7
```

Comment: I don't think the conversion is that direct when ISO weeks are involved, but for something more simple this might work.