# Advanced LINQ/ Lambda Expression

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I have this model:

```
Public Class Tbl_Exercise

    <Key()> Public Property Exercise_ID() As Integer
    Public Property Exercise_Employee_ID() As Integer
    Public Property Exercise_Create_Date() As Date
    <ForeignKey("Tbl_Exercise_Type")> _
    Public Property Exercise_Type_ID() As Integer
    Public Property Exercise_Duration() As Integer

    Public Overridable Property Tbl_Exercise_Type As Tbl_Exercise_Type

End Class
```

I need to get the sum of the `Exercise_Duration` for each week of the year.  I need to then check if the sum for the week is greater than or equal to `150`.  If it is, I need to +1 another variable (a count).  The goal is to display this:

```
# of weeks you've reached 150: X out of Z
```

(Where `X` is the count of weeks greater than or equal to 150 and `Z` is equal to the total number of weeks in the current year.)

**Final**

```
    ' get number of weeks the exercise goal was reached (greater than or equal to the goal)
    Dim exerciseDb = New ExerciseDbContext
    Dim exercise = exerciseDb.Tbl_Exercises.Where(Function(x) x.Exercise_Employee_ID = empId)


    Dim weeks = exercise.ToList.GroupBy(Function(x) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(x.Exercise_Create_Date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday))

    Dim totalWeeks = 0

    For Each week In weeks

        Dim sum = week.Sum(Function(x) x.Exercise_Duration)

        If sum > 150 Then

            totalWeeks += 1

        End If

    Next

    Debug.Print("over150: " + totalWeeks.ToString)
```

Comment: I think I know how to do it if I group them by week, but I don't know if the rest can be done in lambda or if it must be done in VB.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, please provide c# if you can.  (I use VB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example in C#:

```
public class Exercise
{
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Exercise[] ex = new Exercise[]
        {
            new Exercise { CreateDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2012"), Duration = 160 },
            new Exercise { CreateDate = DateTime.Parse("1/8/2012"), Duration = 160 },
            new Exercise { CreateDate = DateTime.Parse("1/15/2012"), Duration = 160 },
            new Exercise { CreateDate = DateTime.Parse("2/1/2012"), Duration = 100 },
            new Exercise { CreateDate = DateTime.Parse("3/1/2012"), Duration = 75 },
            new Exercise { CreateDate = DateTime.Parse("3/1/2012"), Duration = 80 }
        };

        var weeks = ex.GroupBy(x => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(x.CreateDate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday));
        int currentweek = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
        int over150 = weeks.Where(group => group.Sum(item => item.Duration) > 150).Count();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("# of weeks you've reached 150: {0} out of {1}", over150, currentweek));
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow that looks cool, didn't know there was a weekofyear function.  I will try this and get back to you.  Thanks.

Comment: Edited my answer to return the output you requested.

Comment: I am getting an error "No accessible groupby can be called with these arguments" `Dim weeks = exercise.GroupBy(Function(x) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(x.Exercise_Create_Date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday))`  I would rather go with this solution, if I can get it to work, since this is how I program (I use lambda as opposed to linq).

Comment: What does the rest of the stack look like for the error message?

Comment: It's okay now.  I now get a new error that says, "`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetWeekOfYear(System.DateTime, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule, System.DayOfWeek)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`" on line `Dim over150 = weeks.Where(Function(group) group.Sum(Function(item) item.Exercise_Duration) > 150).Count()`

Comment: Looks like a EntityFramework error. I would do a LINQ `select` to project the date and duration to an generic class (like in my example) then do the grouping.

Comment: I had to add .tolist before the where statement.  I will post the final code I am using.  Ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261297/getweekofyear-with-entity-framework

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Globalization;

DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;

var recap = 
    (from e in exercises
     group e by cal.GetWeekOfYear(e.Exercise_Create_Date, 
                                  dfi.CalendarWeekRule, 
                                  dfi.FirstDayOfWeek) 
     into g
     select new 
     { 
        g.Key, 
        Total = g.Sum(x => x.Exercise_Duration) 
     } 
     into p 
     where p.Total > 150
     select p)
    .Count();
```

Comment: Thanks, Wasp.  Good job; this looks like a really awesome way to do it, too.  This is probably better since I can probably just plug and play this :)

Comment: I updated it because I forgot the declaration of the calendar

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to convert this at all to VB.  I even tried to use a converter but it won't work either.