# Fetch Year and Week together using Sql Function in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, sql-function

I need to fetch the year and week together from Date using `SqlFunctions` in Linq.

```
For example:Date="01/12/2014", I need to get 2014-48
```

I can get `week from SqlFunctions.DatePart("ww",Date)` and `year from SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy",Date)`, but how to combine it to `yyyy-ww` or fetch as `yyyy-ww`?

Is it possible get this other than using `SqlFunctions`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you're using Entity Framework, correct?

Comment: Which week number? ISO?

Comment: Week number for 01/12/2014 is 48.

Comment: Other than with `SqlFunctions`? Not straight out of the database, no. If you brought back the records into memory you could do it with a simple LINQ to Objects query, but I'm guessing that that's not what you want to do.

Comment: If the only way is using SqlFunctions, how to do it? I can get week from  SqlFunctions.DatePart("ww",Date) and year from SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy",Date), but how to combine it to yyyy-ww or fetch as yyyy-ww?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11261467/290627

```
entities.WorkingDays.ToList().Where(a => 
         cal.GetWeekOfYear(a.DATE,CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,DayOfWeek.Sunday)
         == cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,
                                             DayOfWeek.Sunday)
```

Based on that answer, in your case this would look something like this:

```
var cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
var result = entities.ToList().Select(c => new {DateFormat = c.DateField.Year.ToString() + "-" + cal.GetWeekOfYear(c.DateField, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday)});}
```

This assumes that you have "DateField" property in your entity class.

Comment: This can get me only week no.

Comment: You can just add year part of your date field in LINQ. This, of course, assumes that LINQ approach is acceptable to you.

Comment: Check my original answer, I adjusted it a bit to better suite your case. Hope it helps now.

Comment: This way brings back all of the date information from the database, not just the parts that OP is asking for.

Comment: It should be noted that .Net's `WeekOfYear` yields a different result then ISO-8601 standards. This blog tells you why and how to get ISO-8601's version:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2006/01/24/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net.aspx

Comment: @icemanind example there does not use any Sql Functions nor its using MVC 4.