# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I am curious as to what the best practice is for performing queries that contain methods/functions not supported by `Entity Framework` with no `SQL` conversion.

For example:

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
Administrator admin = db.Administrators.Where(admin => admin.Username.ToString() == "test");
```

Will not work as the method `ToLower()` has no supported `SQL` conversion.

Currently I do this:

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
Administrator admin = db.Administrators.ToArray().Where(admin => admin.Username.ToString() == "test");
```

However I do not think converting the administrators set to an array to perform these kind of queries is very good performance wise.

Can someone please tell me what the best practice is for these kinds of queries in `Entity Framework`?

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Bad example query I know, but I have run into other instances of this.

Comment: Are you sure your shown code examples are correct? It doesn't show ToLower(), just ToString().

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880011/entity-framework-all-method the ToLower() method should be supported. Haven't tested it.

Comment: ToLower() did not used to be supported, but ToString() still isn't, this is just a generic example and I want to know what to do when I run into issues such as this. So the best answer is to simply use functions that are supported?

Comment: Also is there some way to add your own supported functions on your models?

Comment: Best practice depends on what you're actually trying to do, sometimes you can translate to supported functions (.ToString -> Convert.ToString), sometimes you can reduce enough the result set with supported operators then .ToList() and do unsupported queries in memory, sometimes you can use a stored procedure, a view, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two choices -

- Write a stored procedure and import it
- Push the results into memory using `ToArray()` and then you can use all the methods you want (not great performance unless the initial result set is small).

The Entity Framework query provider has to know how to translate the method call into SQL and while you can develop your own, I don't think you can subclass theirs - so adding your own methods to it won't be easy.  Or, to put it another way, bloody difficult!

It's probably horribly unpopular, but I'm still using a lot of SPs when I get to the real nitty-gritty of data querying.  Although part of the motivation in my environment is whether other non-EF environments need to be able to reproduce similar behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
Administrator admin = db.Administrators.Where(admin => admin.Username.Equals("test", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

beside that if you want to fetch only one entry you should use

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
Administrator admin = db.Administrators.SingleOrDefault(admin => admin.Username.Equals("test", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

or

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
var admins = db.Administrators.Where(admin => admin.Username.Equals("test", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
var admin = admins.First();
```

In case of more than one Administrator with username "test" Where will cause exception

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Administrator admin = (from a in db.Administrators where a.Username == "test" select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the methods found in the [`EntityFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) class.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, he was asking for "methods/functions not supported by Entity Framework with no SQL conversion". Simple string functions  as `ToLower` and `ToUpper` are supported, and as he said, it was a bad example.

Comment: And BTW, `left`, `right` and `reverse` are indeed string functions.