# How To Count Associated Entities using Where In Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have this:

```
        var queryResult = (from post in posts
                    select new
                               {
                                   post,
                                   post.Author,
                                   post.Tags,
                                   post.Categories,
                                   Count = post.Comments.Count()
                               }).ToList();
```

But I need something like this:

```
        var queryResult = (from post in posts
                    select new
                               {
                                   post,
                                   post.Author,
                                   post.Tags,
                                   post.Categories,
                                   Count = post.Comments.Where(x=>x.IsPublic).Count()
                               }).ToList();
```

But post.Comments is a ICollection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
        var queryResult = (from post in posts
                           join comment in comments.Where(x=> x.IsPublic) on post.Id equals comment.Post.Id into g
                    select new
                               {
                                   post,
                                   post.Author,
                                   post.Tags,
                                   post.Categories,
                                   Count = g.Count()
                               })
```

But in all solutions we have this problem [How to use Include and Anonymous Type in same query in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026266/how-to-use-include-and-anonymous-type-in-same-query-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`Enumerable.Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)  like this ?

```
var queryResult = (from post in posts
                    select new
                               {
                                   post,
                                   post.Author,
                                   post.Tags,
                                   post.Categories,
                                   Count = post.Comments.Cast<Comment>()
                                                        .Where(x=>x.IsPublic).Count()
                               }).ToList();
```

assuming `post.Comments` is of type `Comment`

Comment: The problem isn´t the type itself. Entity framework dont support this:
Unable to create a constant value of type 'PostComment'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Comment: You might want to include the exception message in the question post. Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879411/entity-framework-unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-closure-type

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var queryResult = (from post in context.Posts
                select new
                           {
                               post,
                               post.Author,
                               post.Tags,
                               post.Categories,
                               Count = context.Comments.Where(c => c.Post == post).Where(c => IsPublic == 1).Count()
                           }).ToList();
```

Comment: would that way do a query on the comments table for every row on the posts table? (i'm still a linq beginner it's just mild intuition making me ask)

Comment: @Gabriel: No. It will add subselect to query. It will run only single sql query. There is probably no faster way. EF will translate it nicely.

Comment: Same error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'PostComment'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context

Comment: i might just code the SqlCommand (or if using L2s as I do use ExecuteQuery<>) -  and put a TODO: make this LINQ later.

Answer (score 0):

I'd written it as LukLed did but to make it work I'll use the PK of Post entity:

```
var queryResult = (from post in context.Posts
                select new
                           {
                               post,
                               post.Author,
                               post.Tags,
                               post.Categories,
                               Count = context.Comments.Where(c => c.Post.Id == post.Id && c.IsPublic == 1).Count()
                           }).ToList();
```

Or Post.Id could just be written as PostId if forign keys are exposed through the association which I believe it would be more efficient.