# How to use Include and Anonymous Type in same query in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

In [How To Count Associated Entities using Where In Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024199/how-to-count-associated-entities-using-where-in-entity-framework/5026189#5026189) I get this query

But when I access queryResult[0].post.Category or queryResult[0].post.Tags it´s always empty, because I am not using Include.

Include dont work with Projection, as microsoft say at last item here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx

```
var queryResult = (from post in posts
                           join comment in comments.Where(x=> x.IsPublic) on post.Id equals comment.Post.Id into g
                    select new
                               {
                                   post,
                                   post.Author,
                                   post.Tags,
                                   post.Categories,
                                   Count = g.Count()
                               })
```

How I can get the Count in the same query, and Include relationship to Tags and Categories?

Why EF relationship fix-up dont work here?

Comment: It should work fine. Maybe there is something wrong with your model classes. Can you add EF Code First code to this question?

Comment: I did some research, and this is the expected behavior. Relationship fix-up dont works for Many-To-Many

Comment: Similar question with a working answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167547/linq-to-entities-include-anonymous-type-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with 2 queries:

```
var posts =
  from post in context.Posts.Include(p => p.Author).Include(p => p.Tags).Include(p => p.Categories)
  where post.Comments.Any(c => c.IsPublic)
  select post;
var counts =
  from post in context.Posts
  where post.Comments.Any(c => c.IsPublic)
  select new { PostId = post.Id, Count = post.Comments.Count() };
var countDictionary = counts.ToDictionary(e => e.PostId, e => e.Count);

foreach (var item in posts)
{
  System.Console.WriteLine("PostId {0}, TagCount {1}, PublicCommentCount {2}", item.Id, item.Tags.Count, countDictionary[item.Id]);
}
```

By Diego Vega: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/c0bae1c1-08b2-44cb-ac29-68a6518d87bd