# LINQ To Entities + Include + Anonymous type issue

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

Consider:

Class Client

Class Project

Class Ticket

Class Reply

Clients have a sub collection of projects, projects have a sub collection of tickets and tickets have a sub collection of replies.

```
var data = ctx.Set<Ticket>().Include(p => p.Client).
Select(p => new { Ticket = p, LastReplyDate = p.Replies.Max(q => q.DateCreated)});
```

Doesn't work. Neither project nor client are loaded when selecting data this way.

I know how to make it work. My question is why doesn't it work like this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Ladislav mentioned, `Include` only works if you select the `Ticket` entity directly. Since you're projecting other information out, the `Include` gets ignored.

This should provide a good work-around:

```
var data = ctx.Set<Ticket>()
    .Select(p => new 
         { 
             Ticket = p, 
             Clients = p.Client,
             LastReplyDate = p.Replies.Max(q => q.DateCreated)
         });
```

First of all, each Ticket's Clients will be accessible directly from the `Clients` property on the anonymous type. Furthermore, Entity Framework should be smart enough to recognize that you have pulled out the entire `Client` collection for each `Ticket`, so calling `.Ticket.Client` should work as well.

Comment: Thanks. That is also the solution i thought of.

Comment: I should point out to anyone reading this solution that EF doesn't magically populate the `.Ticket.Client` navigation property with entities returned with this projection, so accessing clients through the Ticket object will query the database again.

Comment: @PedroPedrosa: This may have changed in more recent versions of EF. At the time I wrote this answer, EF actually did figure out that we'd materialized all of that ticket's Clients, and so it eagerly loaded that data into that property.

Answer (score 8):

Because `Include` works only if you select entities directly. Once you do the projection `Include` is ignored. I will not tell you why but it simply works this way.

Comment: Do you think Microsoft plans to change that ?

Comment: plus1 *I will not tell you why but it simply works this way.*

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use StriplingWarrior's solution but then cleanse the intermediate data from the final result:

```
var data = ctx.Set<Ticket>()
    .Select(p => new 
        { 
            Ticket = p, 
            Clients = p.Client,
            LastReplyDate = p.Replies.Max(q => q.DateCreated)
        })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(p => new
        {
            Ticket = p.Ticket, 
            LastReplyDate = p.LastReplyDate
        });
```