# EF eager load collection in projection with GroupJoin

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to make a left join with Linq to Entities in EF and eager load a collection in one of the entities.

The left join works with this code:

```
var joinedResult = context.Set<Client>()
    .GroupJoin(
        context.Set<Project>(),
        client => client.Id,
        project => project.ClientId,
        (client, projects) => new
        {
            Client = client,
            Project = projects.FirstOrDefault()
        })
    .ToList();
```

Now the Client entity has a Categories collection I want to load. Since this is a projection, I cannot include the collection before performing the group join, neither after the join since I am creating an anonymous type.

I tried to add the collection in the anonymous type as suggested by [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7168252/2409722) to a similar question:

```
ClientCategories = client.Categories.Select(s => s.Name),
```

but i keep getting an `ObjectDisposedException` when accessing the collection from the Client object outside the business layer.

Accessing the field directly after the query before returning from the business layer like this:

```
joinedResult.ForEach(result => result.Client.Categories.Count() /* NOP */);
```

works, but of course it results in a new database query per result.

How should I proceed to load this collection ?