# Entity Framework with Include and Select together

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following entities ( pseudo code to save space)

```
Program [ int Id, 
          string Name, 
          List<ProgramFoodType> ProgramFoodTypes, 
          List<ProgramFood> ProgramFoods]

ProgramFoodType[ int Id, int ProgramId, int Type, bool IsActive]
ProgramFood [ int Id, int ProgramId, Food Food, FoodType FoodType]
Food [int Id, string Name]
FoodType [int Id, string Name]
```

my task is to get single `Program` with its related `ProgramFoodTypes` with condition ProgramFoodType should be active and `ProgramFoods` with related entities `Food` and `FoodType`

I used the following so far

1- the below query will retrieve the details of `ProgramFoodTypes` and `ProgramFoods` but it will bring all active and inactive `ProgramFoodTypes`

```
var program = mEntities.Programs
                          .Include(p =>p.ProgramFoodTypes)
                          .Include(p =>p.ProgramFoods.Select(f =>f.Food))
                          .InClude(p =>p.ProgramFoods.Select( f =>f.FoodType))
                          .Where(m =>m.Id== Id);
```

2- the below query will retrieve the details but missing the `Food` and `FoodType`

```
var program = (from p in mEntities.Programs
              where p.Id ==Id
              select new {
                 Program = p,
                 ProgramFoodTypes = from pf in p.ProgramFoodTypes
                                    where pf.IsActive
                                    select pf,                  
                 ProgramFoods = p.ProgramFoods // here i can't add include statement
              }).ToArray().Select(m => m.Program);
```

how to include the food and food type in the second query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be:

```
var program = (from p in mEntities.Programs
          where p.Id ==Id
          select new {
             Program = p,
             ProgramFoodTypes = from pf in p.ProgramFoodTypes
                                where pf.IsActive
                                select pf,                  
             ProgramFoods = p.ProgramFoods.Select(y => new {
                 Food = y.Food,
                 Type = y.FoodType
             }) 
          }).ToArray().Select(m => m.Program);
```

Comment: It worked fine, just i added the ProgramFood it self or it will not be retrieved, thank you

Answer (score 4):

For your second solution, I think you can use:

```
var program = (from p in mEntities.Programs
                  .Include(p => p.ProgramFoods.Select(f => f.Food))
                  .Include(p => p.ProgramFoods.Select(f => f.FoodType))
               where p.Id == Id
               select new {
                  Program = p,
                  ProgramFoodTypes = from pf in p.ProgramFoodTypes
                                     where pf.IsActive
                                     select pf,                  
                  p.ProgramFoods 
               }).ToArray().Select(m => m.Program);
```

**update**:
Since you're using anonymous type in your linq query, [Include statements are dismissed.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7168225/337294)
You'd have to load all related `ProgramFoodTypes` on client side, and then do the filtering:

```
var program = mEntities.Programs
                   .Include(p => p.ProgramFoodTypes)
                   .Include(p => p.ProgramFoods.Select(f => f.Food))
                   .Include(p => p.ProgramFoods.Select(f => f.FoodType))
                   .SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == Id);

program.ProgramFoodTypes = program.ProgramFoodTypes.Where(pft => pft.IsActive);
```

You can use `AsNoTracking()` or clone the returned `Program` object in a new object in case you want to make sure your data will be intact on db-side.

Comment: the Food and FoodType still empty in the result

Comment: Ahh I see. That's because you selected anonymnous oobject not the entity itself. updating my answer...

Comment: I was trying to avoid splitting the query and to make it simple, the missing part was that i can Include the food and food type in the anonymous child query, as @tschmit007 mentioned in his answer, thank you for your updates, i think it will work since it was splitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var program = mEntities.Programs
                       .Include(p => p.ProgramFoodTypes)
                       .Include(p => p.ProgramFoods.Select(f => f.Food))
                       .InClude(p => p.ProgramFoods.Select(f => f.FoodType))
                       .SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == Id && m.ProgramFoodTypes.All(t => t.IsActive));
```

Comment: it returned System.NullReferenceException ( Object reference not set to an instance of an object).

Comment: If you mean that `program` is null, that's because no results found that are matching the criteria.

Comment: I think what OP is trying to achieve is to fetch the object but only related ProgramFoodTypes that their `IsActive` are set to true.

Comment: I am getting the result normally but not like what i want when i remove the m.ProgramFoodTypes.All(t=>t.IsActive), it seems the where clause was applied before actually including the entities? something like this