# Entity from Entity Framework is supposed to have a populated list, but it's always empty

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a project for an interview. My project has an `EmployeeService` class for getting employees from the database. Employees can have a list of Dependents. However, this list is always returning as an empty array.

This is what my entity looks like:

```
public class Employee : Person
{
    public ICollection<Dependent> Dependents { get; set; } = new List<Dependent>();
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This is what my `DbContext` class looks like for accessing my database:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext, IAppDbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public AppDbContext()
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Pay> PayEntries { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Dependent> Dependents { get; set; }
}
```

And here are some relevant methods from my `EmployeeService` class. This is the class my controller is using:

```
    public ICollection<EmployeeDto> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        return _dbContext.Employees.Select(e => e).ToList().Select(e => e.ToDto()).ToList();
    }

    public EmployeeDto GetEmployee(int id)
    {
        var employee = _dbContext.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);

        if (employee == null)
            throw new Exception("Employee does not exist");

        return employee.ToDto();
    }
```

---

Now my problem is that my list of dependents is not getting populated. I'm getting an empty array each time from my `DbContext`, and I'm not sure why. Both the `GetAllEmployees` and `GetEmployee` methods always return an empty array of dependents (note, this is not due to that `ToDto()` method. I verified that the dependents are empty prior to reaching that point).

Here is a screenshot of the database tables, confirming Anakin should have the one dependent (I'll add Leia later)

[image]

But I just get this back:

```
{
    "dependents": [],
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Anakin",
    "lastName": "Skywalker"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add `.Include(x => x.Dependents)`

```
return _dbContext.Employees.Include(x => x.Dependents).ToList();
```

PS: try by not using .Select statement since [it breaks Inclusion.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7168225/1118978)

I Advise you to use mapper for mapping source class to destination class dto.

Comment: I'll try that, thank you. I'm not sure what you mean about Select breaking inclusion, so I'll look that up. 

Oh, and I want to ask (since this is for an interview), I am using automapper for mapping to DTO, but I'm using it via an extension method (`ToDto()`). Should I do it differently?

Comment: if you first issue .ToList() then .`Select(x => x.ToDto())` it wont be problem.  your statement is Query (IQueryable) before casting it ToList. After ToList is issued your query is executed on Database. Whatever you select after .ToList wont cause any breakdown

Comment: I put reference to my answer. please check it

Comment: I don't agree that you should not use Select. If you have Employee with Id 4, and it has 1000 Dependants, then every Dependant will have foreign key EmployeeId with the same value 4. It is a waste to send that value a 1001 times. My advice would be: always use Select and select only the properties you actually plan to use. The only reason to use include is if you plan to update the included items.

Comment: I suggest it for this case only. Of course using select has lots of benefits. Did you trace OPs code? His first select breaks inclusion.