# Unable to create a constant value. Only primitive types

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
dbEntities db = new dbEntities();
foreach (ttCategory c in db.ttCategories)
{
    var tags=(from t in db.ttproduktes where t.ttCategories.Contains(c) select t.ttTags);
    foreach (ttTag t in tags)  // here it says:
                               // Unable to create a constant value - only primitive types
    {
       t.ToString();
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please give use more information about your schema (and ideally change your type names to follow normal .NET naming conventions).

Comment: Seems that ttTag (in foreach) is not a valid type.

Comment: "ttCategory" and "ttTag" are your classes names ?
Replace it by "var" in the foreach.

Comment: This could be related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879411/entity-framework-unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-closure-type

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In linq-to-entities, you can't use Contains with a class, you can only use it with a primitive type, so you need to change this:

```
where t.ttCategories.Contains(c)
```

to

```
 where t.ttCategories.Any(x => x.UniqueProperty == c.UniqueProperty)
```

Comment: now i get the error that `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[WT.Models.ttTag]" cannot be converted to Typ "WT.Models.ttTag"`

Answer (score 1):

```
var tags = (from t in db.ttproduktes
            where t.ttCategories.Any(q => q.Id == c.Id)
            select t.ttTags);
```