# EF how to sellect elements that are not in collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 data model classes product, order, orderRow

How to select only those products that are not current order rows?

```
var order = db.Orders.Find(order_id);
var product= db.Products.Where(m => ((order==null) || order.Rows.Count(a => a.Product== m) < 1)  ).AsQueryable();
```

When I try this I get "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Order'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879411/entity-framework-unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-closure-type

Comment: @Thewads yes very similar, but I did not get answer from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions here, but you can extrapolate:

```
var nonSelectedProducts = from product in db.Products
                          where !order.Rows.Any(or => or.ProductId == product.Id)
                          select product
```

Comment: It is more or less I wrote - Error I get is "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Order'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: Hmm it worked - then what is the difference between db.Products.Where().AsQueryable() and from p in db.Products select p

Comment: @SpoksST Shouldn't be any difference but I suspect it might be something with the `Count()`?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do a negative contains on the ids:

```
var productIds = order.Rows.Select(x => x.Product.Id);
var products = db.Products.Where(x => !productIds.Contains(x.Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

i was getting the error as "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Order', so what is did is

```
var nonSelectedProducts = from product in new List<product>(db.Products)
                      where !order.Rows.Any(or => or.ProductId == product.Id)
                      select product
```

and you are set