# Linq "Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1"

Tags: list, linq, null

Exception while null
Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.
The Query is

```
List<string> tempList = context.BusinessEntities.Where(w => RelatedBusinessEntityGuids.Contains(w.BusinessEntityGuid))
                                                .Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
```

if theere is no matching (Null)  then it is getting error ,how could i resolve it,

Comment: what the type for RelatedBusinessEntityGuids abd BusinessEntityGuid.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879411/entity-framework-unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-closure-type?rq=1

Comment: I just recreated your problem exactly as described and everything works, are you sure you don't have null values in `context.BusinessEntities`, `RelatedBusinessEntityGuids`, or any of the `.BusinessEntityGuid` values?

Comment: RelatedBusinessEntityGuids was null , you are rite